# Cómo agregar una línea divisora entre los elementos de menú en Java Android

Tags: android, android-layout, menú

Estoy buscando como separar los elementos del menú con una linea divisora horizontal, es decir que se pueda agrupar los elementos y visualmente con la linea divisora, usando `<group>` no hace nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente menú con `<group>` y no aparece la linea

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.testtheme.MainActivity">

    <group android:id="@+id/grp1">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_theme_default"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settheme_default"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_theme_default"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settheme_red"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_theme_red"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear divisores en un menú, la única forma es usando [setGroupDividerEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuCompat#setGroupDividerEnabled(android.view.Menu,%20boolean)), obviamente cada elemento debe estar definido en un grupo.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

        //Habilita mostrar divisores.
        MenuCompat.setGroupDividerEnabled(menu, true);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar definir un grupo con una `ID` única. Si el grupo tiene diferentes `ID`, se creará un divisor. De esta forma:

```
<group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/item_1" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:title="@string/item_2" />
</group>
```

Comment: Es lo que voy intentando, no acaba de funcionar como el DrawMenu

Comment: Has intentado dibujar la linea y después llamarla por código java?